# CSS and JQuery - How To Stop Slide at each image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need help with my Image Slider.
The Problem is: Every time I click the buttons, the image is not displayed as a full rounded image. I want each image to stop on the exact location so that it will be displaying 5 full rounded images. There's also a problem when hovering the image: when hovering one image, there are unnecessary effects on the next images and an image is shown in the hidden part. I hope you can help me with this, everybody.

Thank you so much.

[Here is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0xnLpesf/3/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="left">
  <button id="left-button">
  <
  </button>
</div>
<div class="center" id="content">
  <img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
  <img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
  <img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
  <img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
  <img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
  <img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
  <img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
  <img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
  <img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
  <img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
  <img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
  <img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
</div>
<div class="right">
  <button id="right-button">
  >
  </button>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.left{
 float: left; 
 width: 8%;
 height: 200px;
 border: 0;
}

img.internal{
 width: 100px;
 max-width:100px !important;
 height: auto;
 max-height:100px;
 border-radius: 100%;
 border: 2px solid transparent;
 margin-left: -4px;
}

img.internal:hover{
  position: fixed;
 border: 2px solid orange;
 overflow: hidden !important;
}

.center{
 float: left; 
 margin-top: 5px;
 width: 540px;
 height: auto;
 border: 2px solid transparent;
 margin: 0;
 overflow: hidden !important;
 /*will change this to hidden later to deny scolling to user*/
 white-space: nowrap;
 border-radius: 55px 55px 55px 55px;
}

.right{
 float: left; 
 width: 10%;
 height: 200px;
 border: 0;
}
```

Comment: @Jay The value is used to let the editor accept link to jsfiddle.

Comment: I'm sorry, This is my first post. The link is listed.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Relevant code belongs directly into your question, not just on external sites.

Answer (score 0):

You had given position fixed in "img.internal:hover"
Here's your updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manoj1991/0xnLpesf/4/).

```
img.internal:hover{
 border: 2px solid orange;
 overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed one of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you missed to pass event as parameter on `click` event which throws error and block further execution of code. check below snippet.

```js
$('#right-button').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#content').animate({
    scrollLeft: "+=100px"
  }, "slow");
});

$('#left-button').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#content').animate({
    scrollLeft: "-=100px"
  }, "slow");
});
```

```css
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 8%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 0;
}

img.internal {
  width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px !important;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  margin-left: -4px;
}

img.internal:hover {
  border: 2px solid orange;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}

.center {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 540px;
  height: auto;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  /*will change this to hidden later to deny scolling to user*/
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-radius: 55px 55px 55px 55px;
}

.right {
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left">
  <button id="left-button">&lt;
  </button>
</div>
<div class="center" id="content">
  <img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png"><img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png"><img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
  <img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png"><img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png"><img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
  <img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
  <img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png"><img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png"><img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
  <img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
  <img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png"><img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png"><img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
  <img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
  <img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png"><img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png"><img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
  <img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
  <img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png"><img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png"><img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
  <img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
  <img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png"><img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png"><img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
  <img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
  <img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png"><img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png"><img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
  <img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
  <img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png"><img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png"><img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
  <img class="internal" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
</div>
<div class="right">
  <button id="right-button">
    &gt;
  </button>

</div>
```